# Cannot install my app getting DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR this error

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently updated my Android studio and it leads to the below issue.

```
Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.*.*-1

 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Can't install because
 provider name
com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service (in
     package com.A.* is already used by com.B.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a new Provider has been added in 8.3.0 (AppMeasurementContentProvider) unfortunately the authorities field in the generated AndroidManifest.xml is not unique therefore apps can't be installed/updated due to INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error.

Your AndroidManifest file (as seen in /build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml) contains the following provider definition:

When we build the project we get the following result in the merged /build/intermediates/manifests/full/prod/release/AndroidManifest.xml

Work-arounds:
Add the following to our own manifest:

```
<provider
            tools:replace="android:authorities"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.google_measurement_service"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Work-around 2:

```
android {
    defaultConfig.applicationId = "my.package.id"
}
```

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=784)